# React private routes not rendering content

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-router

I'm trying to get firebase auth working my react application. Everything is working fine except for my private routes, only pages that have props passed through the components do not render anything when I'm logged in. For example, the path for /create and /blogs don't render anything, while /register works when tested.

Route Code:

```
<PrivateRoute path="/create" exact render={props => (<CreateBlog {...props} addBlog={addBlog}/>)}/>
<PrivateRoute path="/blogs" exact render={props => (<Blogs {...props} removeBlog={removeBlog}/>)}/>
<PrivateRoute path="/register" exact component={Register}/>
```

I also get this error in the console "type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports." whenever I try going to those problematic pages. It points to this line of code (the return line in the PrivateRoute component)  but I can't find anything wrong with my exports. Any help would be appreciated!

Here is my PrivateRoute code:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => {
    const {currentUser} = useAuth();
    return (
        <Route {...rest} render={props => {
           return currentUser ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to ="/login" />
        }} />
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is that you expect in your `PrivateRoute` a `component` but provide a `render` property.

It is a little bit confusing because it would work with a normal `Route`. That one handles on it's own the `component` and `render` difference. But because you wrote your own `PrivateRoute` you need to handle it on your own.

I would rewrite the `PrivateRoute` like this:

```js
const PrivateRoute = ({ component, render, ...rest }) => {
  const { currentUser } = useAuth()

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => {

        return currentUser ? (component ? React.createElement(component, props) : render(props)) : <Redirect to="/login" />
      }}
    />
  )
}
```